# Using Flutter, How to link between Authenticated users and Database in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, mobile

I need to create a collection in cloud firestore each document have the uid Authentication of each  user from Authentication database

Answer (score 0):

you can use the firebase_auth User instance which will have a unique id within the uid variable
and you can use it to build you database schema around it
users collection  every user will have a document the document id = user.uid
and go just like that
also you can use uid as attribute inside any document you want but this is how you link a user with a document base on there uid

Comment: Thank you for  your clarification .can you please provide me any code sample??

Comment: should make things more clear : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sw1Uy3zwsLs